# What is the significance of cat's missing eye?

Tags: analysis, 10-cloverfield-lane

In *10 Cloverfield Lane*, Emmett notices that the puzzle was not complete. The cat's eye puzzle pieces were missing:

[image]

I felt like it was some foreshadowing but didn't get it. Did I miss something? Is there any significance to the missing puzzle piece?

Comment: Only speculation, but it would seem to me this is an indication that both the characters and the audience are only seeing 'part of the picture' as to what is really going on outside of the of the shelter.

Comment: @onewho and/or inside the shelter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer got revealed in ARG, from [postapocalypticmedia.com](https://www.postapocalypticmedia.com/the-10-cloverfield-lane-arg-is-not-your-grandmas-arg/)

> John Goodman’s character Howard Stambler, as twisted as he is, is also
> something of a romantic. You see, he knew that the world was in
> trouble, and made careful preparations for his estranged daughter to
> find him once the shit hits the fan.
>
> One of the preparations involves an ammo box that he buried in a
> field. He filled it with several useful items, a handwritten note, and
> two puzzle pieces:   These same pieces, it turns out, are the ones the
> movie protagonists spend time looking for.

Even the user uploaded a detailed video later: